# Beautiful Soup. Text extraction into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the information from a single web-page that contains multiple similarly structured recordings. Information is contained within *div* tags with different classes (I'm interested in username, main text and date). Here is the code I use:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib
import pandas as pd

href = 'https://example.ru/'

sause = urllib.urlopen(href).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sause, 'lxml')

user = pd.Series(soup.Series('div', class_='Username'))
main_text = pd.Series(soup.find_all('div', class_='MainText'))
date = pd.Series(soup.find_all('div', class_='Date'))

result = pd.DataFrame()
result = pd.concat([user, main_text, date], axis=1)
```

The problem is that I receive information with all tags, while I want only a text. Surprisingly, *.text* attribute doesn't work with *find_all* method, so now I'm completely out of ides.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: an actual example would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

list comprehension is the way to go, to get all the text within MainText for example, try

```
[elem.text for elem in soup.find_all('div', class_='MainText')]
```